# Class attributes reset when imported from package

Tags: python, package

I have a project that is organized something like

```
project/
    __init__.py
    builder.py
    component/
        __init__.py
```

Within `builder.py`, I have a class called Builder that has several class attributes in order to implement the Borg pattern. The trouble arises when I try to import Builder in `component/__init__.py` and make changes to class attributes. It seems that whatever changes I make to the class attributes in the package are undone when the function returns.

UPDATE: Here is a simple example of what is happening.

**builder.py**

```
class Builder(object):
    attribute = True

import component

print Builder.attribute
```

**component/___init___.py**

```
from project.builder import Builder

Builder.attribute = False
```

**Output:**

```
False
True
```

Judging by the fact that two lines are printed, I would guess that the code in `builder.py` is being executed twice, which resets the value of `attribute` to True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a circular import: builder imports component, component imports builder.

At the time builder imports component, builder is not yet fully constructed. Then component imports builder, which executes the rest of builder module (all after `import component`). Later, when component is loaded, builder continues again with everything after `import component`.

Note that the behaviour would be different if component was loaded first!

Basically, you should not do circular imports. Try to organise the code in some other way.

Answer (score 0):

You should really show (a simplified version of) your code.  Something like (assuming e.g. that `project` is in sys.path):

```
import builder
builder.Builder.baah = 'boo!'
```

in `component/__init__.py`, for example, should work just fine with no "undoing" nor "resetting".

But what code exactly *are* you using instead, to perform those "whatever changes"...?